# How to get day-by-day breakdowns from google analytics?

Tags: google-analytics

We use Google Analytics for our website.  I'm curious about where our traffic has been coming from - so the breakdown by what Google refers to as the "source/medium".

However, what I'd really like to get is a day-by-day list, say over the past 90 days. I.e.

```
                         March 1 | March 2 | March 3 | .... | April 11 | April 12
facebook / fbads       |         |         |         |      |          |       
google / organic       |         |         |         |      |          |       
(direct) / (none)      |         |         |         |      |          |       
...                        ...        ...      ...               ...        ...
```

All I can figure out is how to get them for two comparison periods (say, this week vs last) but not for day-by-day.

Any thoughts on how I can get that out of the system?

Comment: Do you need it inside Analytics? Because "day of the month" as a secondary dimension (or "day index" if you need information crossing calendar months) then exported and run through a pivot table in Excel would give you what you want. Alternatively, you could use Data Studio to produce the same result.

Comment: @GeoffAtkins I hadn't heard of DataStudio!  That was great.  Very handy.

Answer (score 1):

This answer comes from @GeoffAtkins's comment.  The answer is to use Google's DataStudio to access the data and work with it.